# using your visual studio 2012 c++ .exe on computers that don't have the .dll(s)

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, glew, freeglut

So I'm making a game using c++ glut and glew, I installed 4 different .dll files into my system folder 32bit and 64bit for both,

so now I'm wondering, since I moved the .exe to another computer and it couldn't run, can I create an installer somehow that would include them? like do normal apps install to the system folders too? or will it automatically detect the .dlls in the same folder as the app or do i have to change something in the c++?

Comment: It should be fine with them in the same folder.

Comment: would it be fine too redistribute it like that because they're open source?

Comment: @SpencorKillen: That wholly depends on the licensing terms, open source has nothing to do with it.  However, if you couldn't distribute them they wouldn't be very useful, would they?